# Адаптивность на форме Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Такой вопрос, я добавляю динамически на форму следующие компоненты:

```
struct sbj_window_data{
    QGroupBox *sbj;
    QLabel *sbj_time,*sbj_locate,*sbj_type,*sbj_name,*sbj_week;
};
QVector<sbj_window_data*> dyn_container;
```

Я записываю их в структуру, и ее помещаю в вектор. sbj_locate должен быть справа в Group box, и для этого я добавил resizeEvent, который пробегается по вектору, и выставляет нужный Label справа в GroupBox.

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*){
for(int i=0;i<dyn_container.size();i++){
    dyn_container[i]->sbj_locate->move(dyn_container[i]->sbj->width()-10-dyn_container[i]->sbj_locate->width(),10);
}
```

}
Но при этот Event применяется только для тех Label которые расположены в текущей вкладке, при переключении в других вкладках все изменяется только при изменении окна. Поэтому я добавил следующий сигнал, который при переходе на другую вкладку выполняет то же что и resizeEvent();

```
QObject::connect(my_tab_widget, SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)), this, SLOT(tabSelected()));


void MainWindow::tabSelected(){
for(int i=0;i<dyn_container.size();i++){
    dyn_container[i]->sbj_locate->move(dyn_container[i]->sbj->width()-10-dyn_container[i]->sbj_locate->width(),10);
}
```

}

Все работает, но терзают сомнения что это не правильно. Подскажите пожалуйста корректен ли данный код, и если нет, то как лучше сделать?

Comment: Используйте лучше layout: QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout или QGridLayout вместо ручного размещения на форме через move

Comment: Я использую, мне необходимо разместить label в определенном виде в QGroupBox.

Comment: Не вижу использования компоновщика (layout) в вопросе :)